# Odoo, Python : ValueError: write() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

this error appear when test the module

i'm trying to make two level validation on sales order
confirm order wont done without the approve art 
by the sales managaer group so this button sent email,print,confirm will not appear whitout approve first

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 955, in exec_workflow
    return request.session.exec_workflow(model, id, signal)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 1111, in exec_workflow
    r = self.proxy('object').exec_workflow(self.db, self.uid, self.password, model, signal, id)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 879, in proxy_method
    result = dispatch_rpc(self.service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 115, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 37, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 188, in exec_workflow
    return exec_workflow_cr(cr, uid, obj, signal, *args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 182, in exec_workflow_cr
    return execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, 'signal_workflow', [res_id], signal)[res_id]
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 164, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 256, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 3572, in signal_workflow
    result[res_id] = workflow.trg_validate(uid, self._name, res_id, signal, cr)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/__init__.py", line 85, in trg_validate
    return WorkflowService.new(cr, uid, res_type, res_id).validate(signal)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/service.py", line 91, in validate
    res2 = wi.validate(signal)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/instance.py", line 80, in validate
    wi.process(signal=signal, force_running=force_running, stack=stack)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 120, in process
    ok = self._split_test(activity['split_mode'], signal, stack)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 248, in _split_test
    self._join_test(t[0], t[1], stack)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 257, in _join_test
    WorkflowItem.create(self.session, self.record, activity, inst_id, stack=stack)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 95, in create
    workflow_item.process(stack=stack)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 116, in process
    if not self._execute(activity, stack):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 162, in _execute
    returned_action = self.wkf_expr_execute(activity)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 313, in wkf_expr_execute
    return self.wkf_expr_eval_expr(activity['action'])
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 291, in wkf_expr_eval_expr
    result = eval(line, env, nocopy=True)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 314, in safe_eval
    return eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 254, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 580, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
ValueError: "write() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'" while evaluating
u"write('is_art_approved', True)"
```

my python code

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
class salesapproval_sale_order(osv.Model):
        _inherit = 'sale.order'
        _columns = {
           'state': fields.selection(
                [('cancel', 'Cancelled'),('draft', 'Draft'),('confirmed', 'Confirmed'),('exception', 'Exception'),('done', 'Done')],
                'Status', required=True, readonly=True, copy=False,
                help='* The \'Draft\' status is set when the related sales order in draft status. \
                    \n* The \'Confirmed\' status is set when the related sales order is confirmed. \
                    \n* The \'Exception\' status is set when the related sales order is set as exception. \
                    \n* The \'Done\' status is set when the sales order line has been picked. \
                    \n* The \'Cancelled\' status is set when a user cancel the sales order related.'),

}
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record id="sale_view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="model">sale.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<button name="print_quotation" position="after">
<button name="approve_art" string="Approve Art" 
states="draft,sent" groups="base.group_user"/>
</button>
<button name="action_button_confirm" position="attributes">
<attribute name="states">art_approved</attribute>
</button>
<button name="print_quotation" position="attributes">
<attribute name="states">draft,sent,art_approved</attribute>
</button>
<button name="cancel" position="attributes">
<attribute name="states">draft,sent,art_approved</attribute>
</button>
</field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: code seems incomplete,  can you include your business logic too.

Comment: And please add the full error traceback.

Comment: Post the total code, where you are facing the error.

Comment: add it check the post please

Answer (score 2):

Your write method should pass field value in dictionary datastructure like

```
write({'is_art_approved', True})
```

Instead of passing it like:

```
write('is_art_approved', True)
```

And in write method `ids` is required param but that depends how code is written. more about write methods is [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.write)

Bests,

Answer (score 2):

`create` or `write` methods in odoo **requires a dictionary (key:value pairs)** of data to be written in the database. From you error code, it shows the wrongly called write method. It should be as follows:

```
obj.write(cr, uid, ids, {'key':'value'}, context=<<your context>>)
```

where `ids` are the record ids for which you need to update data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot some parameters or you used too many. 
the write method should contain the following parameters:

```
 cr #used database cursor
 uid #logged in user
 ids #id from the object youŕe writing to
 data #dictionary of data that has to be written
 context #the given context
```